# Visiting node twice while doing a depth-first run on a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

For some reason, running this short script visits the node B twice (the actual node being visited twice). One very strange thing is that if you look at the two id(tovisit) calls, they will be different in the last run of the function (!). Can anyone spot the problem?

```py
mygraph = {
    'A': {'C', 'B'},
    'C': {'A', 'F'},
    'B': {'D', 'E'},
    'D': {'B'},
    'E': {'B', 'F'},
    'F': {'C', 'E'},
}

visited = set()
def dfs(graph, start):
    print("visiting %s" % start)
    visited.add(start)
    connections = graph[start]
    tovisit = (connections - visited)
    print(id(tovisit))
    for each in tovisit:
        print(id(tovisit))
        dfs(graph, each)

dfs(mygraph, 'A')

~$ python dfs.py
visiting A
visiting C
visiting F
visiting E
visiting B
visiting D
visiting B
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *"they will be different"*? There are multiple paths to `B`, so it will be visited multiple times.

Comment: Hi Jon, that's why I keep track of the already visited nodes, to avoid visiting them again.

Comment: Yes, but you're working *depth first*, so you may already have `B` cued up at a higher level when you add it to `visited`. You need to move the check *inside* `for each in tovisit:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are caching the unvisited neighbours in the set tovisit.  However, some of these may be visited by the depth first search, so they may be visited twice.

Try adding the extra check:

```
for each in tovisit:
        if each in visited:  # Add this line
            continue         # Add this line
        print(id(tovisit))
        dfs(graph, each)
```

Alternatively, mark all the neighbours as being visited as soon as you identify them:

```
 tovisit = (connections - visited)
 visited.update(tovisit) # Add this line
```

In the current code what happens is:

```
Visits A, notes C and B as unvisited neighbours
  Visits C, notes F as unvisited
    Visits F, notes E as unvisited
      Visits E notes B as unvisited
        Visits B, notes D as unvisited
          Visits D
Visits B again!
```

Comment: Hi Peter, well that's why I create tovisit subtracting the already visited nodes `tovisit = (connections - visited)`. Shouldn't that be enough? Also, I find strange that the variable `tovisit` changes its id  while iterating over it.

Comment: tovisit changes because you are in a recursive function, each call of the function will give tovisit a different id.

Comment: Try adding a depth parameter to dfs representing the callstack.  You should see that the ids make more sense then.

Comment: thanks, I understand the issue now. However there's a detail which still puzzles me: In the original code I posted (which as you notes has a bug), if I print the `id(tovisit)` value within the same function call, it changes its value once. You can see it if you run the code. And they should be the same tovisit variable because I'm tracing every function call and I know that there haven't been nothing in the middle of the two prints. How is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I added the call depth tracing as you suggested and I see that the two calls belong to two different depths... OK it starts making more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to wrap the entire logic around a visited check.

```
def dfs(graph, start):
    if start not in visited: #CHECK ADDED BEFORE LOGIC
        print("visiting %s" % start)
        visited.add(start)
        connections = graph[start]
        tovisit = (connections - visited)
        print(id(tovisit))
        for each in tovisit:
            print(id(tovisit))
            dfs(graph, each)
```

Also an aside: set in python does not respect the order you added nodes. In case you want the exact order you visited nodes, you could use a list, but then the membership check in  visited goes from O(1) to O(N). The best alternative would be to use an ordered dict for visited.